# React Link Button doesn't scroll to the top

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

Got a simple problem that I have spent way too much time on. I've got a button, which when clicked opens another component. Since that component appears at the top of the page, I also want that the button would scroll the page to the top. The scrolling thing isn't working. No animations are needed, just that the page would go straight to the top, once the button is clicked.

```
<li><Link to={{ pathname: "/create"}} ><button className="create-button" onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>Create</button></Link></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `button` with `Link` makes the redirect being performed first so the `onClick` will have no effect here. It would probably be better to `scrollTo` in the component rendered on the `/create` page and only do that on mount.

Comment: Yes, a simpler solution was to add scrollTo to componentDidMount on /create page. Thank you for suggestion.